# frisbyjs and jsonschema (SchemaError: no such schema)

Tags: json, jsonschema, frisby.js

I use frisbyjs and module jsonschema, jasmine-node for run.
There is such a scheme name test.json:

```
{
  "error": {
    "type": "array",
    "minItems": 2,
    "items": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "description_ru": {
          "description": "Информация об ошибке на русском языке",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "description_en":{
          "description": "Информация об ошибке на английском языке",
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties":false
    }
  }
}
```

And me needed include him other schemes, example:

```
{
  "title": "Не корректный email",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "status": {
      "description": "Статус операции",
      "type": "integer",
      "enum": [68]
    },
    "error": {
      "$ref": "test.json#error"
    }
  },
  "required":["status", "error"],
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

Both schemes are located in same directory, after run validator i have next error **SchemaError: no such schema**

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely coming from the `{"$ref": "test.json#error"}` line in your schema. It should be saying there's no schema *loaded into memory* called "test.json".

Most JSON Schema implementations don't automatically dereference a schema, you have to tell it what each schema looks like.

You'll need to give the schemas each a URI and import them with `validator.addSchema(require('test.json'))`. See additional information in the [README](https://github.com/tdegrunt/jsonschema/blob/df9016ac84e5e855ea1bf62d32d83a4dc04cf3b1/README.md#dereferencing-schemas).

Alternatively, use a single file and store the definition inside a "definitions" block:

```
{
  "title": "Не корректный email",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "status": {
      "description": "Статус операции",
      "type": "integer",
      "enum": [68]
    },
    "error": {"$ref": "#/definitions/error"}
  },
  "required":["status", "error"],
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "definitions": {
    "error": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for answer. How i can used in frysby?
For example:
` login.frisby.create("Не корректно указан email")
            .post(login.getPath('user.login'),{
                email: "inc@o/rrect@aa@a.@",
                password: "1234tv"
            })
            .expectStatus(200)
            .expectJSONSchema('./schema/login/incorrect-email.json')
            .toss();`